# Positive roots of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $a_i>0$, $i=1,\dots,n$, and put $\overline{a}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. Assuming not all $a_i$'s are equal, take
$$
p(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i (a_i-\overline{a})\prod_{k=1,\dots,n\;k\neq i} (x+a_k)^2.
$$
How to prove that $p(x)$ has exactly one positive root? (this is a conjecture, based on numerical experiments)

Comment: What makes you tho expect that it has exactly one positive root?

Comment: @Seva some numerical evidence, I'll add this to the question

Comment: Can you prove it for $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=3$?

Comment: @Greg Martin: $n=1$ does not satisfy the condition that not all $a_i$'s are equal. For $n=2$ we get $p(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(a_1-a_2\right){}^2 x^2-\frac{1}{2} a_1 \left(a_1-a_2\right){}^2 a_2$ and so clearly the only positive root is $x_0=\sqrt{a_1 a_2}$. For $n=3$ I don't know already...

Comment: If you divide by $\prod (x+a_k)^2$, you can replace the product with the reciprocal of the omitted term, $(x+a_i)^{-2}$.

Comment: For $n=3$ and also for $n=4$ it seems there is just one change of sign in the consecutive terms, so Descartes' rule of signs should kick in and yield at most one positive root. Perhaps one can even inductively show that there is just one change of sign, and a small additional argument shows that there is at least one positive root.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, as suggested by Douglas Zare, we can rewrite $p(x)$ as
$$p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i)^2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i(a_i-\overline{a})}{(x+a_i)^2}.$$
Notice that the number of positive roots of $p(x)$ equals the number of positive roots of 
$$q(x):=\frac{(x+\overline{a})^2}{\prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i)^2}\cdot p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i(a_i-\overline{a})(x+\overline{a})^2}{(x+a_i)^2}.$$

Existence of exactly one positive root of $q(x)$ follows from the next three statements:

(i) $q(0) < 0$;

(ii) $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} q(x) > 0$;

(iii) $q(x)$ is monotonically increasing, i.e., $q'(x)>0$ for all $x\geq 0$.

**Proof.**

(i) It is easy to see that 
$$q(0) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i(a_i-\overline{a})\overline{a}^2}{a_i^2} = \overline{a}^2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{\overline{a}}{a_i}\right)=\frac{\overline{a}^2}{n}\cdot \left( n^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}\right).$$
We have $q(0)<0$ thanks to the [Chebyshev sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality).

(ii) It is easy to see that 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} q(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(a_i-\overline{a}) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 - n\overline{a}^2 = n\cdot \textrm{Var}(a_1,\dots,a_n)>0.$$

(iii) We have
$$q'(x) = 2\cdot (x+\overline{a})\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i(a_i-\overline{a})^2}{(x+a_i)^3},$$
which is positive for all $x\geq 0$, since all summands are nonnegative and cannot all be zero at the same time.

QED

Comment: Neat derivation!